# Scripts missing for GPT-2 fine tune, and inference in Hugging-face GitHub?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, language-model, gpt-2

I am following the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v2.0.0/examples.html) on the hugging face website, in there they say that to fine-tune GPT-2 I should use the script
[run_lm_finetuning.py](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/run_lm_finetuning.py) for fine-tuning, and the script [run_generation.py](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/run_generation.py)
for inference.
However, both scripts don't actually exist on GitHub anymore.

Does anybody know whether the documentation is outdated? or where to find those two scripts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they've been moved around a couple times and the docs are indeed out of date, the current version can be found in `run_language_modeling.py` here https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/language-modeling

Comment: This is missing too.

Answer (score 0):

Links have been moved around again, you can find everything related to language modeling [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/main/examples/pytorch/language-modeling).

All needed information including location of the old script is in the README

Comment: Please post detailed answer and then references.